# jquery dialog popup window problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I added this code in my PopUpWindow.js File.. in my scripts folder

```
var window = "<div id='window' style='display: none;width:190px'></div>";


PopUpWindow = function (titles, message, redirectURL) {
    document.getElementById('window').innerHTML = message;
    $("#window").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 180,
        title: titles,
        width: 500,
        modal: false,
        open: function () {
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close.ui-corner-all').hide();
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if (redirectURL) {
                    window.location = redirectURL;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I have Included this js file in Site.Master page.

But still i am not able to access this PopUpWindow function in any of my aspx page?

is that I am doing something worng?

I am not able to execte this PopUpWindow for showing the Popup Message

```
PopUpWindow("Field to Show","Message","URL redirect");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "window" is being held in a variable, it is not added to the page anywhere before you try to get it by id.

```
    var window = "<div id='window' style='display: none;width:190px'></div>";


    PopUpWindow = function (titles, message, redirectURL) {

    // Add to body (change the selector to whatever's relevant)
    $('body').append( window );
    // Set the innerHTML the jQuery way :)
    $('#window').html( message );
    $("#window").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 180,
        title: titles,
        width: 500,
        modal: false,
        open: function () {
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close.ui-corner-all').hide();
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if (redirectURL) {
                    window.location = redirectURL;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I've only tested this on JSFiddle, and the CSS isn't there, so I can't guarantee there's not more wrong, but this does make a dialog appear if you change display to "block" on `#window'

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that either you are loading this file wrong (bad url) or something else is going on. Could you check and let us know? It could even be a syntax error.

EDIT:
Did you forget to append window to your DOM?

```
var window2 = "<div id='window' style='display: none;width:190px'></div>";

$(window2).appendTo("body")
```

Comment: Thanks Nexxeus. the code which I mentioned that is the code i have it in my js file.. everything is same but I am not able to access this PopUpWindow dialogue?

Comment: IF i ADD Js file to my site.master page I am getting this Error in my page    Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB0.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDR; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 21 Mar 2011 18:27:44 UTC
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 5
Char: 71822
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:50189/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js
Message: 'w.document' is null or not an object
Line: 7

Comment: Edit I think this is because you are redefining the already in-use window object - try the code in my edit.